# Does multiple Google webmaster account for Single website can harm?

Tags: seo

I have hosted a new site this year. I made the webmaster account and verified my site. Now i man i hired for seo made another webmaster account and verified it.

I know that we can do it the way Google has told us at this page
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/92822?hl=en&ref_topic=4564166
But i haven't tried this.

My question is that can it harm my site as there are two different owner for the site and they have verified individually for this site. Can it effects the crawling and indexing of the site.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem to have more than one verified owner in Google Webmasters Tools.

I would still recommend you not to allow anyone but you to verify themselves as owners. You can give them admin access, but you should keep the ownership.

It won't hurt your site in any case.

Answer (score 0):

2 verified owners for a single website doesn't affects you but it reduces your trust value.

So have one webmaster account and give access to other one in the same account (set some privileges) is the perfect solution.